# Simultaneously run of simulation and optimization in Anylogic

Tags: optimization, parameters

In “Anylogic” I created a production chain of a furniture company for five product types. The chain was built of “delay-”, “service-” with “RessourcePool-Blocks” to simulate the production time of the product and the availability of the worker on the machining station.
The goal was to adjust the load profile with the energy production profile of a photovoltaic system. For this purpose, the production time should be choose individual. The production profile become loaded in the simulation from an excel table. Every day the company produce 20 furniture of different types.
The idea to adjust the production time and the kind of furniture (every furniture type have a different production time) was to use “parameter” to determine the start point to begin the production and the selection of product type. I need for each product two parameter.
In an “optimization” “experiment” in “Anylogic” the simulation for one day runs through. The “Objective” is to minimize the amount of energy draw from the grid. After 500 iterations and some adjustments of the value range, I get adapted parameter as result. The resulted value for the parameter in the “optimization” can transfer to the production chain simulation.
My question is:
Is it possible to transfer the resulted parameters automatic to the production chain program, so that I do not need always to run both simulations separately?
I want to simulate for a whole year, to get specific result for different production profile over the year and not start the optimization program and the simulation individual for every day.